# Accessing public functions from inside a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is the first time I write a jQuery plugin without a tutorial. Now (September 28 2014), the jQuery site doesn't work (I don't know why), so I cannot find any resource there.

Below is part of my plugin that reports errors:

```
$(function($){
    $.fn.dialog = function(command, options) {
        var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.dialog.defaults, options );
        //code
        $.fn.dialog.handleCancel = function() {

        };
        $.fn.dialog.handleAccept = function() {

        };
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.dialog.defaults = {
        // some other props
        onCancel: $.fn.dialog.handleCancel(),
        onAccept: $.fn.dialog.handleAccept()
    };
    // code
}(jQuery));
```

When I call the plugin (`$("#dialog1").dialog(/*..*/)`), the browser console, shows the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error is on the line with `onCancel: $.fn.dialog.handleCancel()`.

How can I access these methods, and where should them be? (I also want them to have access to `$(this)` <- for the dialog itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `handleCancel` and `handleAccept` functions are not initialized until you call the `$.fn.dialog` function.  Therefore, they are undefined when you set the dialogs defaults.

Insert this code prior to `$.fn.dialog.defaults`:

```
$.fn.dialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rearranging blocks within the piece , adding a filter , to prevent *both* `handleCancel` and `handleAccept` being called by default; e.g.,

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.dialog = function(command, options) {
      var $el = this;
        // access , pass arguments to methods
        $.fn.dialog.handleCancel = function(c) {
          $el.html(c + "led")
        };
        $.fn.dialog.handleAccept = function(a) {
          $el.html(a + "ed")
        };
        // call `handleCancel` or `handleAccept` ,
        // based on `command`
        $.fn.dialog.defaults = {
        // some other props
        onCancel: command === "cancel" 
                              ? $.fn.dialog.handleCancel(command) 
                              : null,
        onAccept: command === "accept" 
                              ? $.fn.dialog.handleAccept(command) 
                              : null
    };
        var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.dialog.defaults, options );
        //code
        
        return this;
    };
    // code
}(jQuery));

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  $("#result").dialog(e.target.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="accept">accept</button><button id="cancel">cancel</button><br />
Result: <div id="result"></div>
```